# How to fetch data for pre-validation from different service in Microservices?

Tags: microservices

I want to create order and define its contact. But in order to validate that the contact that was provided by the client is valid and also have permission to create a given order, I first need to have the contact entity, which is in the Users service's database.

In a monolit way I would query the Users collection from the same database, run some logic against the entity (for example: check if the user is associated to the organization that the order is creating for) and only by then I would add this order to the Orders collection. And then of course, return a successful response to the client.

In microservices I cannot query the Users collection. I also cannot query the Organisations collection, So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can call the users API and the organisations API to retrieve the information you need, can't you?